# Integral domains, polynomials and division

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

We know that :

> If $K$ is a field and $P\in K[X]$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K,$ then $\alpha\in K$ is a root of $P$ if and only if $(X-\alpha)$ divides $P$.

My question is the following : does this hold for polynomials with coefficients in an integral domain $R,$ and if it doesn't can you give me a counterexample ? I tried to think about the field of fractions, but no managed to find an answer in the general case. Thank you for all your answers !

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: Yes; in fact it holds when the coefficient ring is any commutative ring with 1. The way to show it is use a generalized polynomial division algorithm.

Comment: @ebrahim : thank you for your answer, I did not know that we can do that kind of division - which works here because the coefficient in front of the $X$ is one and so invertible if I well understood !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already indicated in the comments the answer is yes. The easiest way to see this is to note that
$$x^k-\alpha^k=(x-\alpha)(x^{k-1}+\alpha x^{k-2}+\alpha^2x^{k-3}+\cdots+\alpha^{k-1})$$
so for $f(x)=c_nx^n+\cdots+c_1x+c_0$ it is clear that 
$$f(x)-f(\alpha)=c_n(x^n-\alpha^n)+\cdots+c_1(x-\alpha)$$
is divisible by $x-\alpha$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is divisible by $x-\alpha$ precisely when $f(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Nice way to prove it, +1 and thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, let $D$ be an integral domain with a unit.

Then it can be shown via induction (over the degree of the polynomial) that generalized division holds.

In other words, given $P$ a polynomial and $D$ a monic polynomial,  polynomials $Q$ and $R$ exist so that:

$P=QD+R$, where the degree of $R$ is less than the degree of $D$.

---

Going back to our problem, let $P$ be the polynomial, and let $\alpha$ be the proposed root.

We let $D=(x-\alpha)$ and apply generalized division to get:

$P=(x-\alpha)Q+c$, where $c$ is in the integral domain (because the degree is $1$).

Clearly when we evaluate the polynomial at $x$ we get:

$P(x)=0+c$. So $\alpha$ is a root of $P$ if and only if $c=0$, if and only if $(x-\alpha)$ divides $P$.

Comment: Does that not only work when the polynomial ring is a euclidean domain? namely when F is a field then F[x] is an ED?

Comment: No, you don't need the ring of polynomials to be a euclidean domain, it suffices to have division by **monic** polynomials for the result.

Comment: But it need to be an ED to apply the division algorithm no?

Comment: Or is that just special for monic polynomials?

Comment: It is special for monic polynomials, the key thing is that, the leading coefficient is $1$, so we don't need to do division. When you try to divide by a polynomial that is **not monic** you may run into the necesity of inverses, but in this case it's all good.

Comment: I'm trying to see how you define $Q$ and $R$, say $P=a_n x^{n}+\ldots+a_2 x^2+a_1x+a_0$ and $Q=c_nx^{n-1}+\ldots+c_2 x+c_1$ then multiplying by D, I would take $c_n=a_n$, and $R=a_0+\alpha c_1$, the rest of the $c$'s look like I need to solve a system of equations? But I just keep subbing in for the $c$'s to find the next ones in terms of $a$'s and alpha?

Comment: Like I define $c_n:=a_n$, and $c_k:=a_k+\alpha\cdot c_{k+1}$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$

Comment: sure, you can do it like that, but it is complicated. The proof is inductive. It is clear when the degree of $P$ is $1$. so now suppose it is true when $P$ is of degree $n$ or less. Take $P$ of degree $n+1$. Suppose the degree of $D$ is $m$ Clearly $P=D(a_nx^{n-m})+S$, where $S$ is of degree $n$ or less. So $S=DQ+R$ with $R$ with degree smaller than the degree of $D$. Then notice $P=D(a_nx^{n-m}+Q)+R$ as desired.

Comment: @Jorge Is it true that we can do polynomial division with remainder whenever the leading term of the dividing polynomial is a unit? For example, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials where the leading term of $g(x)$ is a unit, then there exists polynomials $d(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)d(x) + r(x)$ where $0\le \deg r(x) < \deg g(x)$?